# Convert master details object to single object

Tags: c#, reflection

Suppose, we have a master details object like as below.

```
public class A
{
  public string PropA{ get; set; }
  public List<B> obj { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
  public string PropB{ get; set; }
  public List<C> obj { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
  public string PropC{ get; set; }
}
```

And another object is

```
public class D
{
  public string PropA{ get; set; }
  public string PropB{ get; set; }
  public string PropC{ get; set; }
}
```

Now we want copy data from master details object A to single object D. Is it possible?. How can i solve this problem. will you give me a common method that will convert all type of master details object to single object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `SelectMany()`:

```
A myA = //...
var Ds = myA.SelectMany(a => a.obj.SelectMany(b => b.obj.Select(c => new D {
    PropA = a.PropA, 
    PropB = b.PropB, 
    PropC = c.PropC})));
```

Or, in query syntax (wow, this looks a lot cleaner):

```
A myA = //...
var Ds = from a in myA
         from b in a.obj
         from c in b.obj
         select new D
         {
             PropA = a.PropA, 
             PropB = b.PropB, 
             PropC = c.PropC
         };
```

Comment: Thanks your reply.I do not know what is the actual object depth path. here it may be C class has another details F and F has another details K. in this way it can make. please tell me a common method.thanks